# vsftpd used for FTP but not user for SFTP

Tags: server, ssh, ftp, vsftpd, sftp

sorry for dumb question, but I am a newbie in Ubuntu administration.
I configure vsftpd service and it work fine when user connect thought FTP
But when user connect thought SFTP vsftpd not used (I stop vsftpd to check)
I see that ftp user "sy" has running process /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
How I can "switch" this process with vsftpd to use it for SFTP connection?
thank you

found possible solution
I'll try and comment if successful
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1717301

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, exactly? AFAIK `vsftpd` does not provide an SFTP service - it provides [FTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS) - different protocol, different port

Answer (score 0):

ok, vsftpd not provide sftp access, so I just block using SFTP on my server with commenting line in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
#Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

as result I can use FTP over TLS with vsftpd (chroot)